# What's the different between ctrl-c and kill -9 when making kafka broker down

Tags: apache-kafka, failover

I am going through the kafka official tutorial, and met a weird problem at [multibroker](http://kafka.apache.org/quickstart#quickstart_multibroker) part.

I will list what I have done briefly:

- run local zookeeper on port 2181
- run three kafka brokers on ports 9092, 9093, 9094
- created a topic with one partition and three replicas: my-replicated-topic
- produced several messages into this topic

then I wanna test the fault-tolerance of kafka. instead of `kill -9` which works correctly as expected, I used `ctrl-c` to terminate the leader of the topic. Here is the problem:

I CANNOT consume any messages from kafka.

What's wrong?

p.s. the commands I used are exactly the same as the tutorial mentioned above
kafka 1.00

--updated
The following is the some key output:

```
 bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic my-replicated-topic
Topic:my-replicated-topic   PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:
    Topic: my-replicated-topic  Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,1,2 Isr: 1,0,2
```

then I ctrl-c to kill the broker 0:

```
 bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic my-replicated-topic
Topic:my-replicated-topic   PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:
    Topic: my-replicated-topic  Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 0,1,2 Isr: 1,2
```

at this time I cannot consume from other brokers

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9093 --from-beginning --topic my-replicated-topic
```

this is the config for broker 0, configs for others are same as this except for the broker id, port and log directory.

```
broker.id=0
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

Comment: Can you share the output of 
`bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic my-replicated-topic`
before and after killing the broker?

Comment: @farazmateen I pasted the output on the top

Comment: You did not say which broker you stoped and you only have one broker on your bootstrap-server list so if it's that one you will not be able to get the meta-data required to connect to any topic partitions. You should list all three brokers on your --bootstrap-server list like `--bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092,127.0.0.1:9093,127.0.0.1:9094`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your offsets.topic.replication.factor=1 so if you kill the broker with the offsets for your consumer, there is no other replica and so you have no offsets.

It is not a fault tolerant config to have replication factor = 1 on your __consumer_offsets topic

Not only will you need to change this config but you will then also have to modify the existing consumer offset topic to be replication factor = 3

Comment: thanks  but you should take a look at the description of this topic: `ReplicationFactor:3 `

Comment: Ya I see that but your consumers offsets are not stored in the same topic as your data. They are stored in the topic __consumer_offsets. You should look at the description for that topic.

Comment: @HansJespersen console consumers do not get added to any consumer group so, with --from-beginning option it should be able to read the messages while they are in the topic.

Comment: @farazmateen that is not true. run `kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list`, then run `kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic foo --from-beginning`, then in a second window again run `kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list`. You will see that console consumer generates a new consumer group id each time it's run with a unique name such as  console-consumer-27970. Then run `kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group console-consumer-27970` and you will see the current offset

Comment: @HansJespersen Thanks for the correction. However, if a new consumer group is added each time, its consumer offset will be stored separately. So when a broker is killed, offsets topic will elect a new leader and new consumer offset will be stored in that. 
I agree that replication for offset topic should not be 1 but I doubt if that is the problem here.

Comment: If __consumer_offsets topic had replication factor > 1 then there would be an ISR on another broker that could be elected as the new leader but that’s not the case because that offsets topic has been configured with replication factor = 1.

Comment: @HansJespersen Right. That makes sense.

Comment: @HansJespersen yes you are right,  and I made a mistake to focus on how to broker was killed, ctrl-c or kill -9 and not realized I kill the different broker at a time

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between exiting a process via `Ctrl+C` versus killing via `kill -9`. `kill -9` will send the `SIGKILL` signal which kills the process and can't be avoided by the process, whereby `Ctrl+C`, equivalent to `kill -3` will send the signal `SIGQUIT`, which can be handled by the process or be ignored.

Comment: you are right , but this isn't the reason.  Because config `offsets.topic.replication.factor=1`, the consumer stopped when the broke which holds the topic __consumer_offsets got down.